# Store Observable and subscribe to it later - Angular 7

Tags: angular, rxjs, local-storage, observable, subscribe

I expect an Angular 7 client to be regularly offline for hours.

Connected: process HTTP requests normally using observables. 
No connection: store the observable somewhere so I can subscribe to it later, when the connection is reestablished.

This code is condensed for brevity:

```
let someObservable = this.service.returnAnObservable();

if (isOnline) {
  // fire off the HTTP request and handle it
  someObservable.subscribe(... stuff ...);
} else {
  *** store the observable somewhere ***
}

// track when network is back online
this.network.connectionChanged.subscribe(backOnline => {
  if (backOnline) this.synchronize();
});

private synchronize(): void {
  let observables = ** get the observables out of storage **
  observables.forEach(ob => {
    // let attempt = new Observable(JSON.parse(ob));
    // let another = ob as Observable<any>;
    // let isThisPossible = <Observable<any>>JSON.parse(ob);

    // however the Observable is reconstructed, subscribe to it
    observable.subscribe()
  });
}
```

Any ideas on this or is it even possible? The observable itself is a nice tidy object, I'd really like to be able to store and rebuild it at will.

Comment: What is the problem? The observable is already a "factory" for the request, as long as you dont subscribe it, it will hold all the information to make the api call. All your code is correct and should work. just use an array for the storage. You can also subscribe the observable multiple times to generate a new api call every time you subscribe, no reason the rebuild it. And you can just store it

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, it is definitely the case that observables can work like that if they are stored in their "original" state - my first approach was to hold onto the observables in a service variable, something like `private observables: Observable<any>[]`. That worked great... until refresh... which re-inits service variables. Ultimately I can't risk the user losing potentially hundreds of submits if they accidentally refresh, so I need a 'stickier' storage solution.

Answer (score 0):

You want a BehaviorSubject, it is a type of observable that retains the last emitted value.

```js
const { BehaviorSubject } = rxjs;

const bs$ = new BehaviorSubject('initial value');

bs$.subscribe(val => { console.log(`First sub ${val}`); });

bs$.next('New value');

bs$.subscribe(val => { console.log(`Second sub ${val}`); });

bs$.next('Another value');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.4.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

See how the value is still available up to the next emit.

You can take a look at my library ngx-rxcache

https://github.com/adriandavidbrand/ngx-rxcache

You can setup a cache item with a constructor function that returns an Observable

Inject the cacheService into you constructor

```
constructor(private cache: RxCacheService) { }

const cacheItem = this.cache.get({
  id: 'Some unique id',
  construct: () => this.http.get('Your data endpoint'),
  autoload: true
});
```

autoload: true will run the constructor function the first time the data is accessed, load: true will trigger it straight away so the data is already loaded when first accessed

You can either subscribe to updates with

```
cacheItem.value$.subscribe(val => { doStuffWithVal(val); });
```

or just look into the cache to see the latest value

```
doStuffWithVal(cacheItem.value);
```

To refresh data from the server you call load

```
this.network.connectionChanged.subscribe(backOnline => {
  if (backOnline) this.cacheItem.load();
});
```

And the constructor function will be rerun.

You can read more about it here if you want

https://medium.com/@adrianbrand/angular-state-management-with-rxcache-468a865fc3fb

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts! I'm a bit unclear on how a `BehaviorSubject` might help - without connectivity the observable will be constructed but not subscribed to, so there isn't really an original value to retain. The cache approach however looks very promising, I'll take a look at your implementation and library today and update later.

Comment: Great library, I plan to use it elsewhere in my app, but I don't think I can apply it to this problem. I am able to cache POSTs made offline and use `.load()` to sync everything when the network comes back. Unfortunately these `cacheItems` are lost on refresh. I've tried several iterations of load/autoload/update as well as `localStorage: true` (which works great for GETs that have already loaded and have value) but the POSTs are not persisted, probably because they haven't been loaded yet? If you have thoughts please let me know - cheers!

Comment: I would need to see you code why the posts are not working. The constructor function doesn't care about http verbs, it just expects an observable being returned.